# Why was the mail sent but not received in zend framework?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm new to the zend framework.

I have a code to send a mail and it's working, but the message is not received by the customer side, but it returns that the mail was sent successfully. Can you teach me how to work with zend_email?

```
public function sendMailStatements($qid,$emails=array()) {
    require_once 'Zend/Mail.php';
    require_once 'Zend/Mail/Transport/Smtp.php';
    try {
        $config = array('ssl' => 'ssl',
            'port' => 465,
            'auth' => 'login',
            'host'  => '127.0.0.1',
            'username' => 'username@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'password');

            $transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.gmail.com', $config);
            Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($transport);
            $mail = new Zend_Mail();
            $mail->setSubject("Quotation LL Sports Exim");

            $body="Dear Sir/Madam<br>Kindly find the attached Quotation and give us your Feed BAck";
            $mail->setBodyHtml($body);
            foreach ($emails as $email):
                 $mail->addTo($email);
            endforeach;
            var_dump($emails);
             if($qid!=""):
                  $fullBaseUrl = getcwd();
                $full_path = $fullBaseUrl . "\\pdfs\\" .$qid.".pdf";
                $content = file_get_contents($full_path); // e.g. ("attachment/abc.pdf")
                $attachment = new Zend_Mime_Part($content);
                $attachment->type = 'application/pdf';
                $attachment->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT;
                $attachment->encoding = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
                $attachment->filename ="quotation.pdf"; // name of file

                $mail->addAttachment($attachment);                  

             endif;


             $mail->send($transport);

             return true;

    } catch (Zend_Exception $e) {
        echo "Caught exception: " . get_class($e) . "\n";
        echo "Message: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
        exit;
        // Other code to recover from the error
    }
}
```

Please let me know where I did wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try to look at the logs of your machine to find out if it has actually sent an e-mail or not. Otherwise you can use tools like [mail-tester](mail-tester.com) to figure out what happens to the mail.

Comment: Maybe the mail ended up inside the spamfolder?